# Where can I find information on sales figure of Apple products?

Tags: iphone, imac, ipod, ipad

I am carrying out some research into Apples product sales over the years. Where can I find information on their sales figures to date? I am looking for information regarding the number of products sold to date, sales of Apple accessories, their market demographic and any other details on who buys Apple products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for **a lot** of data, I can suggest you take a look at these financial quarter results Apple released themselves:

### 2012

[Quarter 2, 2012](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q2fy12datasum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2012](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q1fy12datasum.pdf)

### 2011

[Quarter 4, 2011](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q411datasum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2011](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/fy11q3datasum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2011](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q211data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2011](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q111data_sum.pdf)

### 2010

[Quarter 4, 2010](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q410data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2010](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q310data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2010](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q210data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2010](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q110data_sum.pdf)

### 2009

[Quarter 4, 2009](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q409data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2009](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q309data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2009](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q209data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2009](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q109data_sum.pdf)

### 2008

[Quarter 4, 2008](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q408data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2008](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q308data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2008](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q208data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2008](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q108data_sum.pdf)

### 2007

[Quarter 4, 2007](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q407data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2007](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q307data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2007](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q207data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2007](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q107data_sum.pdf)

### 2006

[Quarter 4, 2006](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q406data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2006](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q306data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2006](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q206data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2006](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q106data_sum.pdf)

### 2005

[Quarter 4, 2005](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q405data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2005](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q305data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2005](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q205data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2005](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q105data_sum.pdf)

### 2004

[Quarter 4, 2004](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q404data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2004](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q204data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2004](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q104data_sum.pdf)

### 2003

[Quarter 4, 2003](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q403data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2003](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q303data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2003](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q203data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2003](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q103data_sum.pdf)

### 2002

[Quarter 4, 2002](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q402data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2002](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q302data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 2, 2002](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q202data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 1, 2002](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q102data_sum.pdf)

### 2001

[Quarter 4, 2001](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q401data_sum.pdf)
[Quarter 3, 2001](http://images.apple.com/pr/pdf/q301data_sum.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Apple discloses many of these informations with their quarterly reports. You'll find many sources discussing and analysing these by having a quick search in Google, but you'll also find the original announcements on Apple's website.

Have a look at http://investor.apple.com/

A listing of all press releases with quarterly reports can be found on this page: http://investor.apple.com/results.cfm